# @KafkaListener is not consuming messages - issue with deserialization

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

Message Producer using Kafka bindings of Spring cloud streams

```
@Component
public static class PageViewEventSource implements ApplicationRunner {

private final MessageChannel pageViewsOut;
private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

public PageViewEventSource(AnalyticsBinding binding) {
    this.pageViewsOut = binding.pageViewsOut();
}

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("priya", "dyser", "Ray", "Mark", "Oman", "Larry");
    List<String> pages = Arrays.asList("blog", "facebook", "instagram", "news", "youtube", "about");
    Runnable runnable = () -> {
        String rPage = pages.get(new Random().nextInt(pages.size()));
        String rName = pages.get(new Random().nextInt(names.size()));
        PageViewEvent pageViewEvent = new PageViewEvent(rName, rPage, Math.random() > .5 ? 10 : 1000);


        Serializer<PageViewEvent> serializer = new JsonSerde<>(PageViewEvent.class).serializer();
        byte[] m = serializer.serialize(null, pageViewEvent);

        Message<byte[]> message =  MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(m).build();

        try {
            this.pageViewsOut.send(message);
            log.info("sent " + message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    };
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

This use below serialization

> spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.key.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
>   spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.default.value.serde=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$BytesSerde

I am Trying to consume these messages in separate Consumer Application via Spring Kafka - KafkaListener

```
@Service
public class PriceEventConsumer {


private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PriceEventConsumer.class);

@KafkaListener(topics = "test1" , groupId = "json", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void receive(Bytes data){
//public void receive(@Payload PageViewEvent data,@Headers MessageHeaders headers) {
    LOG.info("Message received");
    LOG.info("received data='{}'", data);

    }
```

Container factory configuration

```
 @Bean
 public ConsumerFactory<String, Bytes> consumerFactory() {

  Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
  StringDeserializer.class);
   props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
  BytesDeserializer.class);
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "json");
  props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

  return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);

 }

 @Bean
 public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Bytes> 

 kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Bytes> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
  factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
  return factory;
 }
```

With this Configuration Consumer is not picking up the messages(Bytes). If I change Kafka listener to accept String then it gives me below exception :

```
   @KafkaListener(topics = "test1" , groupId = "json", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")

 public void receive(String data){

    LOG.info("Message received");
    LOG.info("received data='{}'", data);

    }
```

**Caused by:**

> org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot handle message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes] to [java.lang.String] for GenericMessage [payload={"userId":"facebook","page":"about","duration":10}, headers={kafka_offset=4213, kafka_consumer=brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer@9a75f94, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=test1, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1553007593670}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"userId":"facebook","page":"about","duration":10}, headers={kafka_offset=4213, kafka_consumer=brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer@9a75f94, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=test1, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1553007593670}]
>       ... 23 more
>   Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes] to [java.lang.String] for GenericMessage [payload={"userId":"facebook","page":"about","duration":10}, headers={kafka_offset=4213, kafka_consumer=brave.kafka.clients.TracingConsumer@9a75f94, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedTopic=test1, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1553007593670}]
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadArgumentResolver.java:144) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:283) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
>       ... 22 more

Any pointers will be very helpful.

Updating POJO Part

Pojo Part ——

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "test1" , groupId = "json", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")

  public void receive(@Payload PageViewEvent data,@Headers MessageHeaders headers) {
    LOG.info("Message received");
    LOG.info("received data='{}'", data);

   }
```

Container factory configuration

```
 @Bean
 public ConsumerFactory<String,PageViewEvent > priceEventConsumerFactory() {

    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "json");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(PageViewEvent.class));



}

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, PageViewEvent> priceEventsKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, PageViewEvent> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
     factory.setConsumerFactory(priceEventConsumerFactory());
     return factory;
     }
```

Producer -

```
  @Override
  public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
  List<String> names = Arrays.asList("priya", "dyser", "Ray", "Mark", "Oman", "Larry");
   List<String> pages = Arrays.asList("blog", "facebook", "instagram", "news", "youtube", "about");
   Runnable runnable = () -> {
    String rPage = pages.get(new Random().nextInt(pages.size()));
    String rName = pages.get(new Random().nextInt(names.size()));
    PageViewEvent pageViewEvent = new PageViewEvent(rName, rPage, Math.random() > .5 ? 10 : 1000);

    Message<PageViewEvent> message =  MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(pageViewEvent).build();
                    try {
        this.pageViewsOut.send(message);
        log.info("sent " + message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: you want to deserialize to bytes or pojo?

Comment: Initially, I was trying to deserialize it with POJO. But my consumer was not picking up messages. Any way is fine but apart from String it is not picking up the data

Comment: Show that part i can help you out with that @PriyaTanwar

Comment: @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, PageViewEvent> priceEventsKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, PageViewEvent> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(priceEventConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

Comment: This was my container factory and I was using String and Json Deserializer for key and value respectively. At the kafka listener end, I had below change : @KafkaListener(topics = "test1" , groupId = "json", containerFactory = "priceEventsKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receive(@Payload PageViewEvent data,@Headers MessageHeaders headers) {}

Comment: Please update this in the post, not in comments @PriyaTanwar

Comment: @Deadpool - updated in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize the record from kfka into POJO, for versions <2.2.x use the `MessageConverter`

> Starting with version 2.2, you can explicitly configure the deserializer to use the supplied target type and ignore type information in headers by using one of the overloaded constructors that have a boolean

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String,PageViewEvent > priceEventConsumerFactory() {

Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "json");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(PageViewEvent.class,false));

}
```

Or by using `MessageConverter`

```
 @Bean
 public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Bytes> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

 ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Bytes> factory =
    new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
 factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
 factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
 return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JsonDeserializer` of package `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer`

Also have trust the json deserializer package `props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, <package-name>)`

Answer (score 0):

the same as to the previous answers this works, add it into application.properties:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.default.type=your.package.dto.yourDto
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.use.type.headers=false
```